Create Transaction Security Policy vis REST API
I am trying to create a Transaction Security Policy through the Tooling API, but I am struggling to get the content right.  I've listed three variations below, but I can't quite get to correct.  Does anyone have an example of creating a Transaction Security Policy this way...or some insight on what's wrong with this JSON?

When I add eventName, I get this

There is also an EventName outside of the Metadata tag, so I tried one more and got a different error.

(Update)  I found the object I am trying to serialize in the Tooling WSDL.  Just need to figure out how to serialize it.  I'm trying lots of options (to get the fully qualified name).
   <xsd:simpleType name="TransactionSecurityEventName">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="ReportEvent"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="ApiEvent"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="AdminSetupEvent"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="LoginEvent"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="ListViewEvent"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="CredentialStuffingEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="ReportAnomalyEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="SessionHijackingEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="ApiAnomalyEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="BulkApiResultEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="PermissionSetEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="FileEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="GuestUserAnomalyEventStore"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="LoginAsEvent"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>


@poz any insights?

Step 1: Construct the policy manually via admin UI Step 2: pull it via Tooling API. Step 3: compare and contrast the payload from step 2 with your attempt.

Seems like a bug or incomplete API as flow or apex are required

@salesforce-sas, I started with the raw response I got from Workbench, but submissions kept saying "You can't include that field (i.e. CreatedById, etc).  I kept removing things until I was here. is there no resource that describes the json structures?  Referencing the fields from the help files doesn't seem to be enough!

Based on here and here, the 2nd of the 3 screenshots appears to be correct. But apart from "eventName", there are 2 other "enumaration of type string": "eventType" and "type", which are both plagued by the same problem to expect complexvalue, when they are declared as strings. (The WSDL of the tooling API puts all into the tns namespace.)

Thanks, @FelixvanHove, I noticed that too, but I don't know how to serialize it. I've tried a bunch of options, but no luck so far.  If anyone has an example of using an enum like that, I'm still looking for that answer.

No need for WSDL or XML. Follow the simple steps in our comment and you'll profit. Not even going to say anything about the XY Problem.

@identigral, we all started with the response. I did. And I read Eric's reference to "raw response" like this. The error "Cannot deserialize instance of complexvalue from VALUE_STRING value CredentialStuffingEventStore" pops up even before removing stuff like "CreatedDate". Or have I overlooked anything? Please give it a try yourself.
